# Putting MaaS behind firewall

Tags: maas, iptables

I can't find anything about the ports to be opened on iptables to protect a  MaaS (Region and Rack controller all in one).

Anyone have tried this ?

Roberto

Answer (score 0):

The list of ports can be found here: [Communication | MAAS documentation](https://docs.maas.io/2.5/en/intro-communication).

#### Rack/region

Each rack controller must be able to initiate TCP connections on the following ports:

```
Port(s)            Description
5240               HTTP communication with each region controller. 
                   Note that port 80 is typically used in high-
                   availability environments. See MAAS HA.
5241 - 5247        Reserved for internal MAAS services.
5248               Reserved for rack HTTP communication.
5250 - 5270        Reserved for region workers (RPC).
```

Comment: I have no idea how to read that. "initiate tcp connections?" does that mean the rack controller should 1) bind to those ports? 2) should be able to use those ports as source ports or 3) should be able to call the region controller on those ports?